# Get an executable path within a fastCGI script

Tags: php, linux, path, fastcgi

My dev machine and my server have different paths for the different python versions installed.

To get the correct path of a certain python executable I made this method

```php
static function pythonPath ($version='') {
    $python = $version === '' ? 'python': '';
    if (preg_match('/^\d(\.?\d)?$/', $version)) {
        $python = 'python'.$version;
    }
    return trim(shell_exec("/usr/bin/which $python 2>/dev/null"));
}
```

On my dev machine I can do this

```bash
$> php -r 'require("./class.my.php"); $path=MyClass::pythonPath("2.7"); var_dump($path); var_dump(file_exists($path));'
string(18) "/usr/bin/python2.7"
bool(true)
```

And on the server I get this

```bash
$> php -r 'require("./class.my.php"); $path=MyClass::pythonPath("2.7"); var_dump($path); var_dump(file_exists($path));'
string(27) "/opt/python27/bin/python2.7"
bool(true)
```

But if I use this method on fastCGI the result of `which` is empty (CentOS 6).
As far as I've read, `which` searches on the user's `$PATH`. And this might be the reason I don't get any result for `which python2.7` since the user that executes the script (my guess `httpd`) has not the same path as the account user.

So, how can I find an executable path within a fastCGI script?

Having the user paths are different. (Untested guess: kept using `which` and get first the full path variable of my server account and load it before `which`)

Answer (score 0):

On my server the scripts are run by the "nobody" user.

Printing `$PATH` from within a script will show that `/usr/bin` is the only executable binaries path set for this user running the fastCGI scripts.

The trick was sourcing my user environment variables before executing `which`.

Since bash profile files can vary on name and so my scripts directory, I made this function to get the correct path.

```php
static function getBashProfilePath () {
    $bashProfilePath = '';
    $userPathData = explode('/', __DIR__);
    if (!isset($userPathData[1]) || !isset($userPathData[2]) || $userPathData[1] != 'home') {
        return $bashProfilePath;
    }

    $homePath = '/'.$userPathData[1].'/'.$userPathData[2].'/';
    $bashProfileFiles = array('.bash_profile', '.bashrc');

    foreach ($bashProfileFiles as $file) {
        if (file_exists($homePath.$file)) {
            $bashProfilePath = $homePath.$file;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $bashProfilePath;
}
```

The final implementation to get the python binary path was this

```
static function pythonPath ($version='') {
    $python = $version === '' ? 'python': '';
    if (preg_match('/^\d(\.?\d)?$/', $version)) {
        $python = 'python'.$version;
    }

    $profileFilePath = self::getBashProfilePath();
    return trim(shell_exec(". $profileFilePath; /usr/bin/which $python 2>/dev/null"));
}
```